# Differentiate folowing expression, how much simplifying?

Tags: derivatives

I have following task:

> Differentiate $$\sec(\sqrt{x})\cdot\tan\left(\frac{3}{3x+1}\right)$$

I got following result:

[image]

However, differentiation is new to me and I'm not sure what I have to do after, How much do I have to simplify the expression? Is there any rule?

Comment: Nothing obvious to me...

Answer (score 1):

As a TA, I can say that for a homework problem you should not simplify at all unless specifically asked. You should stop exactly where you are right now. It is much, much faster to grade a set of problems where some questions test if you know the rules of differentiation and other questions test if you know how to simplify than to have one long calculation with any number of possible mistakes.

The rule is: you only simplify if you are specifically asked to do so, or if you have to do something else to the derivative (eg find where it is zero) and simplifying it would help you in these further calculations.

(This is if the problem is homework or a test. If you are just practising on your own, there is no rule.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obtained the derivative. Tho only thing I should and could do is to factor a very few things and get $$\frac{d}{dx} \sec \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\tan \left(\frac{3}{3 x+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sec \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \left(\frac{\tan \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \tan
   \left(\frac{3}{3 x+1}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{18 \sec ^2\left(\frac{3}{3
   x+1}\right)}{(3 x+1)^2}\right)$$